# "App keeps stopping" is being shown when I'm trying to test an app

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's the main activity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT: Int = 1

    //bluetooth adapter
    private lateinit var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private val bluetoothStatusTv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatusTv)
    private val bluetoothIv: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothIm)
    private val turnOnBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.turnOnBtn)
    private val turnOffBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.turnOffBtn)
    private val pairedBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.pairedBtn)
    private val pairedTv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.pairedDevices)

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //init bluetooth adapter
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter


        // check if bluetooth is available or not

        if (bAdapter == null) {
            bluetoothStatusTv.text = getString(R.string.bluetooth_is_not_available)
        } else {
            bluetoothStatusTv.text = getString(R.string.bluetooth_is_available)
        }

        //set image according to bluetooth
        if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
            bluetoothIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_on)
        } else {
            bluetoothIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_off)
        }
        //turn on bluetooth


        turnOnBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
                //already enabled
                Toast.makeText(this, "ALready on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                //turn on bluetooth
                val intent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                    onActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT, result)
                }.launch(intent)
//                startActivityForResult( intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT )
            }
        }

        //turn off bluetooth
        turnOffBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (!bAdapter.isEnabled) {
                //already disabled
                Toast.makeText(this, "ALready off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                //turn off bluetooth
                bluetoothIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_off)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        }

        //get list of paired devices
        pairedBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
                pairedTv.text = getString(R.string.paired_devices)
                //get list of paired devices
                val devices = bAdapter.bondedDevices
                for (device in devices) {
                    val deviceName = device.name
                    pairedTv.append("\nDevice: $deviceName , $device")
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        result: androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT ->
                if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    bluetoothIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_on)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is on.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not on bluetooth.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }

        }
    }
}
```

The app keeps crashing .
[image]

The app doesn't even open and crashes.
At first I used startActivityforResult() but it was crashing and I thought it might be due to the method being deprecated.
But after the changes it is still crashing and I have tried it on multiple devices.

I have included permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

here's the logcat

```
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of kernel
--------- beginning of system
2023-06-18 16:42:07.086   276-280   vold                    vold                                 E  Failed to find mounted volume for /dev/null/Android/obb/com.example.rawis/
2023-06-18 16:42:07.144   679-750   StorageManagerService   system_process                       E  Failed to fixup app dir for com.example.rawis
                                                                                                    android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code -22)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3025)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
                                                                                                        at android.os.IVold$Stub$Proxy.fixupAppDir(IVold.java:1804)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerInternalImpl.prepareAppDataAfterInstall(StorageManagerService.java:4893)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.AppDataHelper.lambda$prepareAppDataPostCommitLIF$0(AppDataHelper.java:138)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.AppDataHelper.$r8$lambda$3RlktWim_2VfqH429iqZylE48dA(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.AppDataHelper$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:8)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:759)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:482)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2049)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.Installer$Batch.execute(Installer.java:397)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.AppDataHelper.executeBatchLI(AppDataHelper.java:148)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.AppDataHelper.prepareAppDataPostCommitLIF(AppDataHelper.java:143)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallPackageHelper.executePostCommitSteps(InstallPackageHelper.java:2235)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallPackageHelper.installPackagesLI(InstallPackageHelper.java:1007)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallPackageHelper.installPackagesTracedLI(InstallPackageHelper.java:885)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallPackageHelper.processInstallRequests(InstallPackageHelper.java:825)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallParams.lambda$processInstallRequestsAsync$0(InstallParams.java:266)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallParams.$r8$lambda$jbPYK1dOf5qsZh9SAizHgadlSi0(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.pm.InstallParams$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (2543) for package com.example.rawis ----------------------------
2023-06-18 16:42:13.096  2543-2543  Compatibil...geReporter com.example.rawis                    D  Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10172; state: ENABLED
2023-06-18 16:42:13.157  2543-2543  ziparchive              com.example.rawis                    W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-06-18 16:42:13.157  2543-2543  ziparchive              com.example.rawis                    W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-06-18 16:42:13.561  2543-2543  nativeloader            com.example.rawis                    D  Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.rawis
2023-06-18 16:42:13.596  2543-2543  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.rawis                    V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.rawis' set to: 'default'
2023-06-18 16:42:13.597  2543-2543  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.rawis                    V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.rawis: false
2023-06-18 16:42:13.598  2543-2543  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.rawis                    V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2023-06-18 16:42:13.614  2543-2543  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.rawis                    D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-06-18 16:42:13.617  2543-2543  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.rawis                    D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-06-18 16:42:13.773  2543-2752  libEGL                  com.example.rawis                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-06-18 16:42:13.779  2543-2752  libEGL                  com.example.rawis                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-06-18 16:42:13.791  2543-2752  libEGL                  com.example.rawis                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-06-18 16:42:13.906  2543-2543  AndroidRuntime          com.example.rawis                    D  Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
2023-06-18 16:42:13.921  2543-2543  AndroidRuntime          com.example.rawis                    E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.rawis, PID: 2543
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rawis/com.example.rawis.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3551)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:202)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
                                                                                                        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:861)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
                                                                                                        at com.example.rawis.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:27)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3538)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
2023-06-18 16:42:14.736  2543-2543  Process                 com.example.rawis                    I  Sending signal. PID: 2543 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (2543) for package com.example.rawis ----------------------------
2023-06-18 16:42:28.988   679-747   VerityUtils             system_process                       E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/base.apk
2023-06-18 16:42:32.011   679-747   VerityUtils             system_process                       E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~u_uY-Rj62MLJY7ZrG6YGaQ==/com.example.rawis-9qluLLJK7syZRtQV8aRI9A==/base.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things can be improved, but the app crashes mainly because the views are initialized where you define them. You should use the findViewById in the onCreate method after setContentView.

You should also check the logcat window for error logs that point you to the issue.  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: I am new to App-development so I am confused. I tried several things but it keeps crashing could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The errors reason is you're trying to get views reference before they were created. You declared properties in following way:

```
private val bluetoothStatusTv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatusTv)
```

That means it calls in `MainActivity` class constructor, where it's too early. Views are usually created in `onCreate` via `setContentView` method call. So you can use one of the following options:

First - get references later.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT: Int = 1

    private lateinit var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    //mark all views as `lateinit var`
    private lateinit var bluetoothStatusTv: TextView

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bluetoothStatusTv = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatusTv)
        //and so on for other views
    }
}
```

Second - use properties without storing a value. In this way each call will trigger `findViewById`, so it's going to be slower if you call it more then once.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT: Int = 1

    private lateinit var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private val bluetoothStatusTv: TextView get() = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatusTv)
}
```

Comment: why did you use get() in "private val bluetoothStatusTv: TextView get() = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatusTv)" and how is it different from the way i declared ?

Comment: In this way properties body isn't called in counstructor, but called each time you get its value. You can imagine it as getter function. But don't forget to use it after `setContentView`. And as I said, every time you call such property would be called `findViewById` method - value wouldn't be stored.